# Symfony2 - assets not loaded when use_controller is set to false

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic, symfony-2.8

I dumped assetics and set `use_controller` to `false` in `config.yml`:

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

But now assets are not loaded! Shouldn't `use_controller` be used for dynamic loading when assetics are not dumped?

I load assets in twig like this:

```
{% stylesheets filter='scssphp' output='css/style.css'
'bundles/index/scss/main.scss'
%}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to tell wich bundles to load

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ AppBundle, AnotherBundle ]
```

Also don't forget to run `assets:install`

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink --relative
```

NOTE: `--symlink --relative` won't work in Windows